# What exactly is this goblin doing here?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, fantastic-beasts-where-to-find-them

This goblin took a wand from this person and handed it over to this person here:

[image: animated GIF of the goblin]

What exactly is this goblin doing here?

Comment: It is not giving the same wand from one to another wizard/witch. It picks the new wand with the left hand and gives the OTHER finished polishing one with it's right hand to the waiting wizard/witch :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a house-elf, and it's shining wizards' wands using some kind of feather machine.

> SCENE 20
>
> INT. MACUSA LOBBY-DAY
>
> NEWT'S POV-They move up a wide staircase and enter the main lobby-a
> vast, impressive space with impossibly high vaulted ceilings.
>
> High up a gigantic dial with many cogs and faces emblazoned with the
> legend: MAGICAL EXPOSURE THREAT LEVEL. The hand on the dial points to
> SEVERE: UNEXPLAINED ACTIVITY. Behind it hangs an imposing portrait of a
> majestic-looking witch: Seraphina Picquery, MACUSA president.
>
> Owls circulate, witches and wizards in 1920s dress are hard at work. Tina
> guides an impressed-looking Newt through the bustle. They pass **several
> wizards sitting in a line, waiting to have their wands shined by a house-elf who operates a complex contraption of feathers**.
>
> Newt and Tina reach an elevator. The doors open to reveal Red, a goblin
> bellboy.
>
> <sub>*(Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them: The Original Screenplay)*</sub>

Comment: Think shoeshine

Comment: https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Wand_polishing_machine

Comment: It's like polishing stuffs with cotton wheel (I'm thinking polished black piano, although it's been used for regular wooden furniture and surfaces too).